# R merging tables with some same & different columns

Tags: r

I want to merge two tables into a third table like this

```
|1|data|ID|average| |1|average|condition|
|2|abc |10|50     | |2|50     |cold     |
|3|abc |11|75     | |3|75     |hot      |
```

into

```
|1|data|ID|average|condition|
|2|abc |10|50     |cold     |
|3|abc |11|75     |hot      |
```

However what I'm getting is this:

```
|1|data|ID|average|condition|
|2|abc |10|50     |         |
|3|abc |11|75     |         |
|2|    |  |50     |cold     |
|3|    |  |75     |hot      |
```

when trying

```
  if (length(table_data_list) > 0) {
    merged_table_data <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), table_data_list)
    selected_table_data(merged_table_data)
```

I can't use merge(df1,df2, by = "average", all = TRUE) because of two reasons

1. there are more than just 2 tables that may contain data, could be 3, could be 20 or even 100 different tables
2. the 'by = average' argument has to be changed each time two or more tables with the same column name are introduced which are not 'average'

Comment: probably you can try `merge(df1,df2, by = "average", all = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi Ekon! Welcome to StackOverflow. Just to clarify, are you joining them all together like a snake? 1 to 2, then those to 3, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  data = "abc",
  ID = 1:2,
  average = c(50, 75)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  average = c(50, 75),
  condition = c("cold", "hot")
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  condition = c("cold", "hot"),
  location = c("canada", "mexico")
)
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

df <- reduce(dfs, full_join)

# Output
  data ID average condition location
1  abc  1      50      cold   canada
2  abc  2      75       hot   mexico
```

Comment: yes & no, that would be the output I want however some of the data between the tables overlaps

Comment: are you saying that in your data, some of the tables don't overlap?

Comment: it might be good instead of telling us about the data, instead showing us the data. Otherwise, we will keep on solving the problem you have put to us, only for you to move the goalposts further away 

Comment: the data in the tables is slightly unorganized so occasionally lets give your example 3 variable columns, df1 has 1 unique column and shares one with df3 and 1 with df2
df2 has 2 unique columns and only shares one with df1, assume df3 might share a column with an unknown dfx in the future.
I hope I haven't over complicated it

Comment: I think the fastest/easiest way of solving this would be to modify your example/my example to make it so that it reflects the uniqueness of your code. That way, if it works for the example, it will work for the real thing. Can you do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

merged_table_data <- Reduce(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y))), table_data_list)